# TCPDF not formatting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tcpdf

I'm using an ajax call to print a pdf and email it to user, but the problem is that the data in the pdf is not formatted.

**Here's my ajax call**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
      $('.simpleCart_items').css({'position:':'relative'});
      $('.headerRow div').css({'display':'none'});
      $('.item-remove').css({'display':'none'});
       $('.itemRow').css({'position':'absolute'}, {'left':'0px'}, {'top':'50px'});
      $('.item-name').css({'position':'absolute'}, {'left':'50px'}, {'top':'0px'});
      $('item-price').css({'position':'absolute'}, {'left':'150px'}, {'top':'0px'});
      $('.item-total').css({'position':'absolute'}, {'left':'250px'}, {'top':'0px'});
      var data = $('#yhteystiedot').serializeArray();
      data.push( { name: 'cartContent', value: $('#emailedcart').html()});
      //alert (data);return false;
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url: "order/order.php",
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(){ alert("Jotakin meni pahasti pieleen! Yritä uudelleen?");
 },
    success: function() {
 alert("Onnistui");
        }


  });
  return false;

    });
  });        
});
```

It adds style to the data that is being pushed to the script, but it doesn't look like it should. Here's a screenshot about it:
[image: pdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, here is the corrected answer.

Use only **INLINE CSS** to work with TCPDF like;

```
<table style="width: 100px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; height: 20px; text-align:center; font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large;" colspan=11>
        REPORT
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Or wrap inside your code like `<style>p{color:red;}</style>`

TCPDF has class issues. Send this HTML data using AJAX. Try like this and comment here.

Comment: The data pushed has classes, but trying to use css in style tags didn't work .

Comment: Seems like I had done something wrong, but `<style>p{color:red;}</style>` seems to be working.